# How to add a navigation bar at once for all screen?

Tags: javascript, iphone, appcelerator-mobile

I would like to ask a question in Titanium mobile. I am finding the way to add one custom navigation bar to all the screens in my project. Currently,I can't find any way to do it. for each window now, I do like this:

```
win.barImage='images/navigation.png';
```

I don't wish to do:

```
`win2.barImage='images/navigation.png';`
win3.barImage='images/navigation.png';
```

for all the screens. This is kinda trouble some, I want to find the way to add just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Titanium to add navigation bar you add a navigation group.
After adding a navigation group you simply add window to it i.e those windows that should be having your navigation bar..
here is the code for that:

```
 //First create a main window
   var win= Titanium.UI.createWindow();

  //one more window that will be shown first.
  var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
  title:'window 1'

  });

// Add a navigation group
 var nav = Titanium.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
 window: win1
 //you can do other customization 
  });

 //Add navigation group to main window
  win.add(nav);
```

Now suppose you want to navigate to another window on a button click
then on the event listener of that button you can write this simple code.

`nav.open(win2,{animated:true});`

win2 is the another window that you create

For more reference you can refer there API doc. here is the link.
[Titanium API Doc](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest)